# How to resolve Radzen Blazor error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: blazor, radzen

I'm getting the following error while using DataGrid on Radzen Blazor. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The issue happens on a simple Radzen Datagrid, with or without any data in the Datagrid. The Datagrid would load fine on first load, but as soon as you click Sort or Group, that error comes up in F12 (on browser windows, it tells you there's error and asks you to Reload).

I haven't figured out the cause but I've figured a way to get rid of the error through trial and error. It took me more than half a day, so I figure this could be helpful for someone else. I'll post my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was to downgrade 2 Nuget packages that were on latest version to a previous version that I know was working fine on my other project:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate: change from 7.0.9 to 7.02.
Radzen.Blazor: 4.14.4 to 4.10.2

I've tried downgrading just one of the 2 above instead of both. No, that didn't work.